discoverability or which-key-style UI for `C-x 8` prefixes?
You can get various accented letters with C-x 8 and using comma, backtick, apostrophe, and others for the particular accent. For example:

C-x 8 ' e gives é
C-x 8 ` a gives à

And there's other options with the C-x 8 prefix:

C-x 8 a > gives → and < gives the left-pointing arrow.

So I'm wondering how I could find other options under that C-x 8 prefix. I have which-key enabled, but it doesn't show anything (just the emoji prefix and RET for insert-char). I've tried C-h k C-x 8 C-h but that just says "C-x 8 C-h is undefined".
I also tried C-x 8 C-h, and with my configuration, that just shows the following in the minibuffer/echo area:
RET : insert-chart e : +prefix
C-x 8-  n : next-page, p : previous-page, u : undo-key, d : toggle-docstrings, h : help, a : abort 1..9 : digit-arg

I know there's all kinds of stuff there. How can I find all the stuff under that prefix/keymap?
And, related, if I have some accented character in mind, how could I find the corresponding C-x 8 ... sequence to use?

Please check the answer. There's more stuff to discover, but I'm done with it at this point :-)

BTW, thanks for asking this question: I learned a lot by trying to answer it.

Answer
Do C-x 8 C-h: you'll get this in a *Help* buffer:
> Key translations Starting With C-x 8:
V Global Bindings Starting With C-x 8:

Key             Binding

C-x 8 RET   insert-char

C-x 8 e +   emoji-zoom-increase
C-x 8 e -   emoji-zoom-decrease
C-x 8 e 0   emoji-zoom-reset
C-x 8 e d   emoji-describe
C-x 8 e e   emoji-insert
C-x 8 e i   emoji-insert
C-x 8 e l   emoji-list
C-x 8 e r   emoji-recent
C-x 8 e s   emoji-search

[back]


The > on the first line (and the V on the second line) is a button. Click it to expand the heading and voilá!
With 20-20 hindsight, the answer is glaringly obvious, but I was blind and missed it all this time and saw it only when trying to reply to OP's comment below.
EDIT: With which-key-mode enabled, C-x 8 C-h shows (as the OP mentions in his edit to the question and in a comment below)
RET : insert-char e : +prefix
C-x 8-  n : next-page, p : previous-page, u : undo-key, d : toggle-docstrings, h : help, a : abort 1..9 : digit-arg

and you need to press an extra h to see the display I show above.

[Leaving the earlier answer below to remind me to look...]

Summary
I found a hint by searching the NEWS files etc/NEWS.29 and etc/NEWS.28 for the string C-x 8. They pointed me to the iso-transl library which I then proceeded to read.
The keymap you are interested in is iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map, defined in the iso-transl library. You can view it with which-key-show-keymap. There are several prefix keys in that keymap and I don't know how to dive into them with which-key facilities, but you may know more about that (in which case, please edit this).
It turns out that iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map is actually inserted into key-translation-map (see Keymaps for Translating Sequences of Events for more details. Also see the read_key_sequence() function in keyboard.c but that's heavy going).

One way to find out what's in the keymap is to use the following:
M-x which-key-show-full-keymap RET iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map

It shows all entries in the keymap.

A second way is to find out what the prefix characters are:
M-x which-key-show-keymap RET iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map

will show you (see Notes below).
Once you know that e.g. ' is a prefix character in the map, then you can add C-h to the prefix key sequence in the standard way: C-x 8 ' C-h will show you what's hiding behind that prefix (you'll need to click on the > to expand the drop-down). Similarly for the other prefix characters.

One last thing: I don't know why C-x 8 C-h does not show everything that's hiding behind that prefix: just RET and the emoji stuff is shown as you mention - that may be a bug). [This is wrong: See the Answer section at the top.]

Notes
Here's a summary of the prefix keys:
" - generally adds umlaut
' - generally adds acute accent
* - various symbols
, - generally adds a cedilla
. - just a couple of translations here - etc/NEWS.29 says "future expansion"
/ - generally adds a ring or a slash
1 - inline fractions like 1/2 ?
2 - ?
3 - inline fraction 3/4 ?
= - generally adds a macron to letters
A - the only thing I could find is the AE diphthong 
N - the only thing is the No abbreviation for number
O - the OE and oe diphthongs
^ - numeric superscripts and circumflex letters
_ - numeric subscripts; also some dashes e.g. n for an en-dash and m for an em-dash
` - generally adds a grave accent to letters
a - just the two arrows you mention, plus a= for a double-pointed <-> arrow, and the ae diphthong
~ - generally adds a tilde to letters

BTW, I got most of this from the definition of iso-transl-char-map in the iso-transl library (use locate-library to find it).
You can try C-h v iso-transl-char-map but it's less informative.

That's super useful! Thank you. My next question: how did you figure that out? In the spirit of emacs being the "self-documenting" editor, how would I go from "there's some keymap stuff under C-x 8, to knowing which keymaps to poke around with?

I cheated: I searched the source code of Emacs. But I was blind: see the  new Answer section at the top. Not sure whether to :-) or to :-(...

Before checking the source code, I found a hint in etc/NEWS.29 and etc/NEWS.28 by searching for C-x 8 in them.

For the minibuffer stuff I see -- something from which-key, vertico, or...I'm not sure -- turns out I need to do h for "help" to get the Help buffer with the "key translations" expandable section that you describe.

It's which-key-mode that causes this: I added a note to the answer to cover this case too. Thanks!
